# Mysql filter subquery

Tags: mysql, timestamp, subquery

I am using Mysqli

How can I do a single query that filters a subquery result? Is it possible?

I need to find users from a subquery result in a particular timestamp period.

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE (**using subquery results i.e SELECT ...**) BETWEEN 2017-01-08 09:00:00 AND 2017-01-08 12:00:00.

I should get back Mr A and Mr B.

**Subquery results:**

```
TimeIn                   User      TimeOut
2017-01-06 10:00:00      Mr A      2017-01-08 11:00:00
2017-01-07 10:00:00      Mr A      2017-01-08 12:00:00
2017-01-08 10:00:00      Mr A      2017-01-08 13:00:00
2017-01-08 09:00:00      Mr B      2017-01-08 11:00:00
```

Thank you for your kind help as I am quite lost on how to do this.

Comment: yes  SELECT * FROM (using subquery results i.e SELECT ...) as subtable Table WHERE subtable.TimeIn BETWEEN 2017-01-08 09:00:00 AND 2017-01-08 12:00:00.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  select ...
) subquery_alias_name
where timeIn BETWEEN '2017-01-08 09:00:00' AND '2017-01-08 12:00:00'
```

Don't forget to give the subquery an alias name

Comment: where subquery_alias_name.timeIn BETWEEN '2017-01-08 09:00:00' AND '2017-01-08 12:00:00'    to avoid conflicts

Comment: When only one table or subquery is involved then you don't need to refer the table name of each column